# Производительность WPF для WinFormHost

Tags: wpf, winforms, directx

Если я отображаю на форме WinForm контрол, для его прорисовки тоже используется аппаратное ускорение ?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ - да, используется, и по тем же правилам, что и для прорисовки обычного wpf приложения(уровень оптимизации зависит от версии directX, 9.0 и выше - максимальная оптимизация.).

Вам, так или иначе, нужно сначала описать контрол wpf, а уже потом его встроить в вашу форму(Это я описываю то, как все работает на уровне сборки). Так вот то, wpf, строится по правилам wpf. DirectX используется, да.

Ссылку на какую-то конкретную статью не могу дать, т.к. подробного рассмотрения именно этого вопроса я нигде не нашел.